# lua gsub %b <-- how does this work?

Tags: lua, gsub

In the following lua code:

```
function interp(s, tab)
  return (s:gsub('($%b{})', function(w) return tab[w:sub(3, -2)] or w end))
end
```

what does the %b mean?

and how does this match stuff like "${name}" ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%bXY` matches a sequence of characters that starts with `X` and ends with `Y`. Thus, `%b{}` matches `{......}` for any characters in between the braces.

The overall pattern in your example code first matches a `$` character followed by a `{`, any number of characters, and then a `}`.

Comment: found on a wiki that %b also ensures that there are equal number of X&Y's inside. Which is kinda cool too.

Comment: This is explained in the manual in http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1 -- see "A pattern item can be..."